# Wheel chart bold arc descriptions

Tags: tikz-pgf, charts

I am using version 2.0 of the [wheelchart](https://ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart) package. The description of such a diagram can be put outside of the wheel chart (`data`), on the wheel chart (`wheel data`) or curved on the wheel chart (`arc data`).

Using the first two options, I can also make the text bold via `textbf`, but when I use it with `arc data` (which is the desired option), compiling the document never stops.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\usepackage{wheelchart}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \wheelchart[
    data = ,
    %data = \textbf{\WCvarC}, % This works (but wrong location)
    %wheel data = \textbf{\WCvarC}, % This works (but wrong location)
    arc data = \WCvarC, % This works (but not bold)
    % arc data = \textbf{\WCvarC}, % This does not work
    ]{
        1/red/Text,
        2/green/More Text,
        3/yellow/Even More Text
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package `wheelchart` (which I wrote) loads the package `tikz` so `\usepackage{tikz}` was removed.

The text in the key `arc data` can be made bold by using `|\bfseries|` in the key `arc data`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\wheelchart[
  arc data=|\bfseries|\WCvarC,
  data={}
]{%
  1/red/Text,
  2/green/More Text,
  3/yellow/Even More Text%
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and your package! In fact, I also had tried "\bfseries", but without the "|...|". How do they work - are they specific to your package or general LaTeX commands?

Comment: @dn1h The key `arc data` uses the decoration `text along path` which uses the syntax `|\bfseries|`. More information can be found in [pgfmanual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) in the section about `TikZ Library decorations.text`.

Comment: Thanks, that explanation and reference helped a lot!